# Visual Basic SaveDialog missing dll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, savefiledialog

I have written a user interface in Visual Basic that sends commands to AutoDesk Inventor to create 3D CAD assemblies. Towards the end of my program, the CAD file is saved and a SaveDialog box comes up. It was working perfectly fine for a while, but now there is an error. Here is the relevant code segment:

```
SaveDialog.Filter = "Inventor Part | *.ipt|Step File | *.stp"
SaveDialog.DefaultExt = "ipt"
SaveDialog.ValidateNames = True
SaveDialog.ShowDialog()
```

On the last line shown, I get a run-time error as follows:

> "The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is
>   missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this
>   problem."

After closing this error message, the SaveDialog box comes up anyway and works perfectly fine. Of course, on the compiled version the error box never actually shows up and the program simply hangs up indefinitely.

I have search for solutions to this problem for two days. I used Dependency Walker and found a list of other dlls that are reportedly missing, most of them under the MSHTML.DLL

I figure there is probably something that is not referenced correctly in my program, but I'm not sure where to look. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Somebody made a big mistake and copied an operating system DLL from a newer version of Windows onto this machine.  Pretty hard to find back, a lot of shell extensions get loaded when you use SaveDialog.  Ask around, two days ought to narrow it down a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the **KB2999226** (Universal CRT) which is part of the Visual C++ Redistributable failed to install. ***Is your automatic updates turned OFF?***

**Solution**

Install Windows Updates:

1. Go to *Start - Control Panel - Windows Update*
   and click on *Check for updates*. Install all available updates. After the updates are installed, restart your computer. After the restart repeat the steps above again until no more updates are available.
2. Download the Visual C++ Redistributable:

   For Windows 64-bit
   **http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x64.exe**

   For Windows 32-bit
   **http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x86.exe**
3. Run the vcredist_x64.exe (64-bit) or vcredist_x86.exe (32-bit) and select Uninstall. Run the .exe again and select Install

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer! I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that I am using Visual Studio 2013. Will updating my computer and reinstalling the Redistributable fix the compiled program? Do users of the program have to go through the same process? Thanks!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the compiled program, if the user doesn't have the correct update's then it will be a problem for them as the update would be missing. When you reference the `dll` and it's installed on the client machine it will look for it, if it doesnt exist they will have a problem.

Comment: Hmm, I see... It is interesting that the save dialog still works, though.

Comment: Well it is part of the framework itself, it should still show. The issue is something with the update itself, it's missing something (not sure what failed) hence the error.

Comment: The computer I am having issues with is a company computer that I do not have admin rights to. I will check around to figure out what has happened.